# canvas.delete(ALL) not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I'm currently making the graphical portion of a poker game in Tkinter with Python 2.7, but I'm having trouble with redrawing the canvas at the moment. For some reason `self.canvas.delete(ALL)` won't delete my buttons or background image label. I've tried `pack_forget()` in my `redrawALL()` function but that doesn't seem to be working either.

```
from Tkinter import *

class PokerGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("PyPoker")
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width = self.width, height = self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.drawStartScreen()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def drawStartScreen(self): 
        self.bgImage = PhotoImage(file = 'startbg.gif')
        self.bgLabel = Label(self.root, image = self.bgImage)
        self.bgLabel.pack()
        self.bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        self.btnPlay = Button(self.root, text = "Play", command = self.playGame)
        self.btnInstructions = Button(self.root, text = "How To Play", command = self.showInstructions)
        self.btnPlay.pack()
        self.btnInstructions.pack()
        self.btnPlay.place(relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.4, anchor = CENTER)
        self.btnInstructions.place(relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)
        return

    def playGame(self):
        self.redrawAll()
        return

    def showInstructions(self):
        self.redrawAll()
        return


    def redrawAll(self):
        print "trying to delete all"
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.btnPlay.pack_forget()
        self.btnInstructions.pack_forget()
        return
```

Comment: So what is the final problem? What doesn't work now?

Comment: There's nothing in the canvas to delete because you never placed anything in self.canvas...at least not in the code you posted.

Comment: Ok, that I can understand, not actually adding things to the canvas, but I'm unable to make any of the buttons go away with pack_forget() either, which I just edited in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas has no element added by `self.canvas.create_*()` (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html)

Probably you want to remove buttons.

Do NOT use `.pack()`, `.place()`, `.grid()` at the same time. They are three different layout managers.

Use `.pack()` OR `.place()` OR `.grid()`

You have used `.place()` for your elements so you have to use `.place_forget()`

Working code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class PokerGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("PyPoker")
        self.root.geometry("1280x720")
        #self.width = 1280
        #self.height = 720
        #self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width = self.width, height = self.height)
        #self.canvas.pack()

        self.drawStartScreen()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def drawStartScreen(self): 
        self.bgImage = PhotoImage(file = 'startbg.gif')

        self.bgLabel = Label(self.root, image = self.bgImage)
        self.bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        self.btnPlay = Button(self.root, text = "Play", command = self.playGame)
        self.btnPlay.place(relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.4, anchor = CENTER)

        self.btnInstructions = Button(self.root, text = "How To Play", command = self.showInstructions)
        self.btnInstructions.place(relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)

    def playGame(self):
        self.redrawAll()

    def showInstructions(self):
        self.redrawAll()

    def redrawAll(self):
        print "trying to delete all"
        self.btnPlay.place_forget()
        self.btnInstructions.place_forget()
        self.bgLabel.place_forget()

PokerGame()
```

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you so much. I didn't realize they should be separated. Thank you.

Comment: @user3006675 by the way: if you don't add elements to canvas you can use `self.root.geometry("1280x720")` in place of canvas.

Comment: @user3006675 by the way: Good organized code. And you don't have to use (empty) `return` at functions end.